# I want to create multiple anchors in android 'arcore geospatial'

Tags: android, android-studio, arcore

I want to create multiple anchors in android studio.

However, when the script is written as below, only the last 3 anchors are displayed. Any solution?

Or how should I write the code?

```
    fun CreateMakers(startApp: Boolean) {
    CreatedMakers = true

    // 지구 객채가 트레킹상태인지 확인.
    val earth = session?.earth ?: return
    if (earth.trackingState != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
        return
    }

    if (startApp) {
        // 앵커가 이미 생성되어 있다면 분리처리
        earthAnchor?.detach()

        // 새로운 앵커 생성
        earthAnchor = earth.createAnchor(
            36.36584044154765, 127.34448328614235,
            earth.cameraGeospatialPose.altitude - 1.5,
            0f, 0f, 0f, 1f
        )


        var earthAnchor2: Anchor? = null
        earthAnchor2?.detach()

        // 새로운 앵커 생성
        earthAnchor2 = earth.createAnchor(
            36.36580480414705, 127.34450038522482,
            earth.cameraGeospatialPose.altitude - 1.5,
            0f, 0f, 0f, 1f
        )


        var earthAnchor3: Anchor? = null
        earthAnchor3?.detach()

        // 새로운 앵커 생성
        earthAnchor3 = earth.createAnchor(
            36.36572677978114, 127.34450273215772,
            earth.cameraGeospatialPose.altitude - 1.5,
            0f, 0f, 0f, 1f
        )
    }
}
```